# What happen when you have multiple apps that support the same external accessory protocol?

Tags: ios, external-accessory

What happen when you have multiple apps that support the same external accessory protocol? Which app will iOS launch?

Comment: Boon have you got an answer to this question?

Comment: @TommasoResti Not yet.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's documentation:

```
    Note: If more than one third-party app registers to handle the same URL scheme, there is currently no process for determining which app will be given that scheme.
```

Comment: Boon didn't talk about URL scheme but External Accessories protocols... Ex: com.yourcompany.mydeviceprotocol

Comment: @TommasoResti You are right, it's protocol, not URL scheme.

Answer (score 0):

AS we known the app bundle ID is unique,So at a time the iPhone can only open one APP in the foreground